# Email overload ISPConfig 3 Server... Hacked?

Tags: debian, postfix-mta

Since late yesterday the email queue to a specific user have risen to over 45,000. The emails are all undeliverables for messages that the user did not send - at least intentionally.

Here is a snippet of the mail.log file.. many of the from addresses are non-existant users, the domain is correct, but not the user.

Any ideas what is going on and how I can stop it?

p.s. I replaced my real domain with "mydomain.co.uk". The only live user on this domain is a user called "mike".

Jun 22 19:28:05 server1 postfix/smtpd[5305]: 6843DFB270: client=81.61.129.17.dyn.user.ono.com[81.61.129.17], sasl_method=LOGIN, sasl_username=mike@mydomain.co.uk
Jun 22 19:28:05 server1 postfix/cleanup[5499]: 3B2B5FB269: message-id=
Jun 22 19:28:05 server1 postfix/qmgr[4391]: 3B2B5FB269: from=, size=715, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun 22 19:28:05 server1 postfix/smtpd[5159]: ABF72FB271: client=unknown[37.218.171.206], sasl_method=LOGIN, sasl_username=mike@mydomain.co.uk
Jun 22 19:28:05 server1 postfix/cleanup[5594]: B1DECFB26C: message-id=
Jun 22 19:28:05 server1 postfix/qmgr[4391]: B1DECFB26C: from=, size=680, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun 22 19:28:05 server1 postfix/smtpd[5474]: ED465FB272: client=unknown[181.112.50.130], sasl_method=LOGIN, sasl_username=mike@mydomain.co.uk
Jun 22 19:28:06 server1 postfix/smtpd[5057]: 189E4FB273: client=unknown[27.75.56.22], sasl_method=LOGIN, sasl_username=mike@mydomain.co.uk
Jun 22 19:28:06 server1 postfix/cleanup[5645]: 0C65CFB267: message-id=
Jun 22 19:28:06 server1 postfix/qmgr[4391]: 0C65CFB267: from=, size=690, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun 22 19:28:06 server1 postfix/cleanup[5515]: 127F5FB26E: message-id=
Jun 22 19:28:06 server1 postfix/qmgr[4391]: 127F5FB26E: from=, size=697, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun 22 19:28:06 server1 postfix/cleanup[5644]: 6843DFB270: message-id=<8REPFY1T-UQLX-NXWH-JAL6-GBV9JM53NE4P@mydomain.co.uk>
Jun 22 19:28:06 server1 postfix/qmgr[4391]: 6843DFB270: from=, size=703, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun 22 19:28:06 server1 postfix/cleanup[5598]: E73C2FB25F: message-id=
Jun 22 19:28:06 server1 postfix/cleanup[5607]: BEDB4FB26D: message-id=
Jun 22 19:28:06 server1 postfix/qmgr[4391]: BEDB4FB26D: from=, size=674, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun 22 19:28:06 server1 postfix/qmgr[4391]: E73C2FB25F: from=, size=690, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun 22 19:28:06 server1 postfix/smtpd[5052]: 95065FB274: client=unknown[94.99.25.28], sasl_method=LOGIN, sasl_username=mike@mydomain.co.uk
Jun 22 19:28:06 server1 postfix/cleanup[5646]: 9858BFB26B: message-id=
Jun 22 19:28:06 server1 postfix/cleanup[5643]: 37753FB26F: message-id=
Jun 22 19:28:06 server1 postfix/qmgr[4391]: 37753FB26F: from=, size=827, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun 22 19:28:06 server1 postfix/qmgr[4391]: 9858BFB26B: from=, size=692, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun 22 19:28:06 server1 postfix/smtpd[5357]: A9E14FB275: client=unknown[181.211.189.214], sasl_method=LOGIN, sasl_username=mike@mydomain.co.uk
Jun 22 19:28:06 server1 postfix/smtpd[5305]: C5767FB276: client=81.61.129.17.dyn.user.ono.com[81.61.129.17], sasl_method=LOGIN, sasl_username=mike@mydomain.co.uk
Jun 22 19:28:06 server1 postfix/cleanup[5593]: 69984FB26A: message-id=
Jun 22 19:28:06 server1 postfix/qmgr[4391]: 69984FB26A: from=, size=715, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun 22 19:28:07 server1 postfix/smtpd[5208]: 17F14FB277: client=unknown[190.233.125.58], sasl_method=LOGIN, sasl_username=mike@mydomain.co.uk
Jun 22 19:28:07 server1 postfix/cleanup[5641]: ED465FB272: message-id=
Jun 22 19:28:07 server1 postfix/qmgr[4391]: ED465FB272: from=, size=715, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun 22 19:28:07 server1 postfix/cleanup[5613]: ABF72FB271: message-id=
Jun 22 19:28:07 server1 postfix/qmgr[4391]: ABF72FB271: from=, size=706, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun 22 19:28:07 server1 postfix/smtpd[5304]: 85087FB278: client=unknown[37.150.230.145], sasl_method=LOGIN, sasl_username=mike@mydomain.co.uk
Jun 22 19:28:07 server1 postfix/cleanup[5515]: C5767FB276: message-id=
Jun 22 19:28:07 server1 postfix/qmgr[4391]: C5767FB276: from=, size=701, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun 22 19:28:07 server1 postfix/smtpd[5494]: 9DBA9FB279: client=unknown[14.167.36.85], sasl_method=LOGIN, sasl_username=mike@mydomain.co.uk

Answer (score 1):

your email account's login information has been intercepted. 
When I look at the IP addresses (I looked at 4) they come from Peru, Ecuador, Saudi Arabia and China.

Change your password and restart sasl